# Flex Align-items: center; Doesnt allow me to use Justify-content: flex-end; in the same block

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm trying to get the Nav Bars ul and li's to go to the end (right) and there I'm going to push them 150px away with margin to center it. It worked but then I wanted to center the logo and nav bar's ul and li's using Flex Align-items: center; but then justify - flexend wont work. Can't see too figure out why, I usually don't use flex although I should I guess.

Also I can't use things like `<header>`, `<b>` so I have to make a div around it when using flex, is that normal?

Here is the HTML that's wrong.

```
    <div class="header">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class = "logo" />
    <ul class = "nav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class = "active">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">OUR PROCESS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS that's wrong.

```css
.header{
display: flex;
align-items: center; /* Here's the align items im talking about*/
background-color: #d40050;
height: 112px;
width: 100%;
}
.logo{
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 150px;
width: 11rem;
}
.nav{     /*Think this is what's bugging*/
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end; /*This is the flex end I'm talking about*/
 margin-left: 35%;
}
.nav li{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 30px;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.nav li a.active{
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: #aa0040;
 padding: 3px 12px 3px 12px;
}
.nav li a.active:after{
 content: ' ';
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 border-top: 10px solid #aa0040;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 position:absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 100%;
 margin-left: -10px;
}
```

P.S - Here's the website live: tsuts.tskoli.is/2t/2809984199/skapalon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `justify-content` property on the flex container.

```
.header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around; /*Add this line of code*/
    background-color: #d40050;
    height: 112px;
    /*Remove this
    width: 100%;
    */
}
.logo{
    display: inline-block;
    /*
    Remove this:
    margin-left: 150px;
    */
    width: 11rem;
}

/*
Remove this:
    .nav{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     margin-left: 35%;
}
*/
```

Comment: It worked flawlessly, thank you so much ! Been wrapping my head around that for a while now !